# Uln2003 stepper motor controller chip fried?

Tags: raspberry-pi

So I may have fried 6 boards and am a little unsure as to why.

The apparatus is a rubiks cube solver. A quick Google search says the torque required to rotate a face is between 38mnm and 247mnm which the motors should almost definitely be able to handle? Says full step 28byj-48 motor can  deliver 1.288nm of torque at 200ma.

I had them all individually working with the 5v  power supply of a raspberry pi. When I hooked up a 5vdc 3a transformer in parallel to each of the motor controllers they didn't spin (unsure if the apparatus has to much load for the motors to handle and thus overloaded the chip) or (unsure if I wired them incorrectly for some reason).

Do the motor controllers pull too much current if to much load is applied to the motor? Enough to break the transistors?

Maybe I rotated the motors a bit getting the cube in place forcing them to enduce voltages to the ic.

Now when I connect only 5v to any of them the chip overheats and I have to unplug it. Should I be buying more darlington transistor ics to replace them, am I missing something? Or should I be buying servos instead? (it would suit the application better, quicker spin etc)

Comment: If you give us a model number for the controller and a wiring diagram, someone might be able to help. If you have the correct controller for your motor, these are fairly easy to use.

Comment: I screwed up big time. Turns out, the ribbon connector for the breadboard was flipped backwards... I feel like an idiot. So, I didn't fry them, and I didn't wire it wrong(kind of)... Cheers mate.